# Double quotes added to tag

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to echo a string from php that has a `<b>` in it. When receiving the string, it comes with an extra double quote in the bold tag and it does't aply on the word I want to highlight.

The php:

```
$lang['hello'] = 'Hello mi <b>name</b> is koke.';
```

Index php:

```
<li><a><?php echo $lang['hello'];?></a></li>
```

What i see in the Google chrome dev tools:

```
<li><a>"Hello mi "<b>"name "</b>" is koke.'</li></a>
```

Is there any way to have a bold word echoing from php?

thank you!

Comment: what version of PHP? is this all the code or are you working with a specific CMS / framework?

Comment: Last version, and I'm not workingwith any framework.

Comment: What did you expect to see?

Comment: Does it really show a single quote instead of double quote after `koke.`?

Comment: Are you sure you're not calling `htmlentities()` or `htmlspecialchars()` anywhere in your code?

Comment: what is "last version" ?

Comment: There is **no reason** PHP would change the content of included HTML-elements in a string. Unless you put the variable through some sort of parser beforehand. With the code in the example, the output does not match the original content, hence something is happening along the way.

Comment: I have tested the code you provided and it works as expected. Make sure you are using a plain text editor like Notepadd++ or even plain Notepad (or whatever the MAC equivalent is)